# Слой GeoTIFF на OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

Я работаю над проектом, в котором собираюсь загрузить файл GeoTIFF в качестве слоя, аналогично тому, что я делал в QGIS. К сожалению, я сталкиваюсь с некоторыми трудностями, и мне действительно мог бы пригодиться ваш опыт.

Я загрузил файл GeoTIFF на геосервер и написал следующий код.Но слой tif файла все равно не виден, отображается просто карта.
[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcKbR.png)

```
import './style.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image.js';
import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS.js';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/web_map/wms',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'web_map:Sablino_baza',
        },
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver',
      }),
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([30.800289, 59.662412]),
    zoom: 14,
  }),
});
```

Comment: в вашем вопросе нет самого важного: описания проблемы, с которой вы столкнулись, и сформулированного запроса к сообществу. стоит это исправить. и, кстати, не стоит создавать конструктор с именем `Map` (не смертельно, но всё же не хорошо).

Comment: Верно подметили, исправил,дополнил. Это тестовый пример поэтому map по умолчанию оставил. Главное разобраться в чем проблема.